# How to get specific text from a string in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have a string from which I need to extract specific texts

```
let str = 'id = "Test This is" id ="second" abc 123 id ="third-123"';
let res = str.match(/[^id ="\[](.*)[^\]]/g);
console.log(res);
```

I want the texts in ids only `['Test This is','second','third-123']`
But I am getting `[ 'Test This is" id ="second" abc 123 id ="third-123"' ]`
The whole text after first id which I don't want.I need help with the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern uses a negated character class where you exclude matching the listed individual characters, and also exclude matching `[` and `]` which are not present in the example data.

That way you match the first char *T* in the string with `[^id ="\[]` and match the last char *;* in the string with `[^\]]` and the `.*` captures all in between.

I would suggest using a negated character class to exclude matching the `"` instead:;

```
\bid\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OuC7hv/1)

```js
let str = 'id = "Test This is" id ="second" abc 123 id ="third-123"';
let res = str.matchAll(/\bid\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/g);
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(/\bid\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/g), m => m[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this down to a non-greedy regular expression indepedent of where the quotes fall in the string:

```js
let str = 'id = "Test This is" id ="second" abc 123 id ="third-123"';
let res = str.match(/".*?"/g);
console.log(res);
```